Boundness of purely imaginary powers of Bessel potential
Let $s\in \mathbb{C}$ with $0\leq \operatorname{Re}s<\infty$, $f\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^n$. We define the Bessel potential $\Lambda_s$ of order $s$ of $f$ as $$\Lambda_{s}f=\mathfrak{F}^{-1}\left((1+4\pi^2|\xi|^2)^{-s/2}\mathfrak{F}f(\xi)\right).$$ I want to prove that for $1<p<\infty$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a positive constant $C$ only depending on $p$ such that $$\|\Lambda_{it}u\|_p\leq C\left(1+4\pi^2|t|^2\right)^{(n+1)/2}\|u\|_p.$$ I tried to use some bound related to the Hormande multiplier theorem since we have controlled the bound of the multiplier $m_s=(1+4\pi^2|\xi|^2)^{-s/2}$ on the norm of $\Lambda_s$ as an operator of $L^p$. However i'm not able to relate it to make appear the value $t$ and the power to the $n+1$. This is an excercise from Michael Taylor's Partial Differential Equations III: Nonlinear Equations (excercise 13.1).
Thanks in advance!

The powers of t appear when you differentiate the symbol with.r.to $\xi$. In the Mikhlin--Hormander Theorem, the norm of the operator on $L^p$ depends on a few derivatives of the symbol

Could you please elaborate a little more?

One version of Mikhlin-Hormander states that if
$$
|\xi^\alpha \partial^\alpha m(\xi)|\le B
$$
for all $|\alpha|\le[n/2]+1$, then $m(D)$ is bounded on $L^p$ with norm $\le CB$. You need only estimate the constant $B$. Your symbol is $m(\xi)=(1+4\pi|\xi|^2)^{-it/2}$. Compute the derivatives of $m$ and check that the derivatives of order $k$ are bounded by $(1+|t|)^k|\xi|^{-k}$.
